# defaultDocument and customErrors

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a problem with the setting up default redirect and custom error page for asp.net.
I just want to display the error page whenever an error occurs. However it will always be directed to the defaultDocument, even if i removed the defaultDocument block.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

My web.config is as below:

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On"
                 defaultRedirect="~/Common/Error.aspx" />
....
</system.web>
....
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="~/Account/Login.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You probably forgot to remove authentication for Error.aspx. What happens when you're not logged in and you call the Error.aspx page directly?

Comment: That page is just plain html, no master page, no vode behind at all

Comment: It doesn't matter. What happens when you access the page directly via its URL while you're not logged in?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. It still redirects me to the defaultDocument.

Comment: Dang it, I found the problem. In the aspx page I inherits the wrong class. Thanks for your help anyway.